# Tesing Laravel API Routes using POSTMAN

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

I am very sorry if my question sounds foolish. I am new to Laravel. I develop some API in Laravel to be used in Angular, but a bit confused about what to type in POSTMAN in order to test the APIs. The project name is '**ntiapi**'

I have written the API in the Controller. Also, I have done the api.php in routes

**api.php**

```php
Route::post('/register', 'AuthController@register');

Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');

Route::post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');

Route::get('/tasks', 'TaskController@index')->name('tasks.index');

Route::post('/tasks', 'TaskController@store')->name('tasks.store');

Route::get('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@show')->name('tasks.show');

Route::put('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@update')->name('tasks.update');

Route::delete('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@destroy')->name('tasks.destroy');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

I have this `http://localhost:ntiapi/api/`

How do I add each of the routes to `http://localhost:ntiapi/api/`
in order to test the api on the POSTMAN. I mean the complete url. For example `http://localhost:ntiapi/api/login`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no route prefix or group prefix it should be

```
http://localhost/ntiapi/public/api/login
```

and if you are running artisan server (`php artisan serve`)

it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login` or `http://localhost:8000/api/login` whatever you prefer.

Comment: What about Route::get('/tasks/{task}', 'TaskController@show')->name('tasks.show');

Comment: @user11352561  create a show method, that will take instance of Post model like ‘function show(Task $task){}’ and you can get single post, simple route-model binding.

Comment: @user11352561 sorry I made post instead of task, it is because I am traveling and replying from phone.